# Trane xv80 3 blinks

Tags: hvac

Trying to be as thorough and concise as I can, zero experience with hvac.

I have a year 2002 Trane xv80 that is giving me the three blink code, which indicates a pressure switch issue.  I disconnected both the low speed and high speed switches, blew into them, and they seem to be making the right kind of clicking noise as I blow or suck.  Kind of a cluck-cluck noise.

When I power up the furnace, the main blower starts to circulate are thru the ducts.  However the inducer motor is not kicking in after 30 or 45 seconds which by memory is when it should kick in, followed by the igniter.  My theory is if the inducer will not spin, then the pressure switches sense inadequate draft and they will then not allow the igniter to ignite, which in turns means no gas will flow and burn, and thus no heat.

I have installed a new flame sensor only because I cleaned it last year and it seemed to solve the problem.  However, it may have been a coincidence.  But, at approx $12 it was worth a shot.  I think the igniter is OK, it ignited a few times over the past few days as I have been troubleshooting, butno longer will ignite.

I unplugged the inducer motor - three wires in the plug, a fourth green is external and goes to a grounding terminal.  I put the multimeter on the inducer plug and have continuity.  I then inserted the probes into the plug coming from the circuit board and checked voltage after starting the furnace.  Nothing registered after a couple minutes of watching, but I may have been doing it incorrectly

Looking for advice.  Is there a way to tell if the inducer motor works?  I can insert a screwdriver and the fan blade spins.  I am not opposed to removing it altogether. Or is there a way to test the circuit board to determine if it is sending voltage to the inducer and if yes, how much should it send and where should I place the probes?

Or would disconnecting the clear plastic tubes from the pressure switches fool the board into thinking all and allow the inducer to go?  I am not opposed to ordering parts, just want to know what to replace.

Comment: The blower should not start immediately, it should only start after ignition and a 45 second start delay. Are you sure you've got your motors right?

Comment: Sorry for confusion, here's what's happening. The big blower - they unit that sucks in air through the filter and blows air into the ducts fires up as soon as I make a call for heat if I dial the Trane xv80 to "heat" and "fan".  Nothing from the smaller inducer motor (brand FASCO)

Answer (score 1):

The normal sequence of operation is:

1. Thermostat calls for heat.
2. Control module runs self check, and verifies 1st stage pressure switch is OPEN, and limit switches are CLOSED.
3. Draft blower is energized.
4. 1st stage pressure switch closes.
5. Igniter warm up begins (17 seconds).
6. Gas valve opens.
7. Flame sensor confirms ignition within 4 seconds.
8. Delay to FAN ON begins (45 seconds).
9. FAN ON delay elapses, and blower motor is energized.

It sounds like you're having a problem at step 3. Where either the control module is not energizing the draft motor, or the draft motor is dead.

I'm not familiar with your specific unit, so I'm not exactly sure which speed the control module runs the draft motor at. I would guess that 1st stage uses low speed, but I could be wrong.

To verify the motor is being energized, follow this procedure.

> ***WARNING:*** You'll be working on live equipment. If you're not comfortable with this, please contact a local licensed professional.

1. Turn power off to the unit, using either the breaker, or the serviceman's switch.
2. Remove the wire harness from the draft motor.
3. Restore power to the unit, and trigger a call for heat.
4. After a delay, measure the voltage between the white *IND-N* pin (pin 3), and the red *IND-LO* pin (pin 2) on the inducer motor wire harness.
5. Measure the voltage between the white *IND-N* pin (pin 3), and the black *IND-HI* pin (pin 1) on the inducer motor wire harness.

You should measure line voltage (~120 volts) between the white wire, and one; or both, of the colored wires. If you don't, the problem is with one of the other limits or the control module. If you do, the problem is likely with the motor.

---

You mentioned that the blower motor is starting, as soon as the thermostat is calling for heat. If this is the case, that could point to an open limit switch. As the blower should not come on until **after** ignition, during normal operation.

Comment: Yes, I think my problem is at step three as well.  The draft blower (FASCO inducer) is not energizing.  Yet it spins fine if I flick it with a screwdriver, and on the odd occasion it did work, it spins without problem. I will investigate with a multimeter and let you know what I find.

Comment: I tried the multimeter on the plug of the FASCO inducer.  I got the following after a call for heat (thermostat set at 80, actual house temp 59, I am cycling the breaker to create the heat call).  Leads in white-red: 0  Leads in white-black, four calls, 12, 3, .3, 7.6 - volts   Leads in red-black: 1, .1. .3  I'm not getting ~120 volts at any time.  I can hear the "click" meaning thermostat is trying to get the inducer to spin up, but nothing.  Please let me know what else to check.

Comment: Is there a model number of the control board?  Is there a model number on the inducer motor?  Is there a wiring diagram printed on the motor? If the board is bad, there's not much to do aside from replacing it.  But they're usually expensive, so you want to be sure that's the problem.

Comment: @user1276141 You've followed the reset procedure?

Comment: There should be a 12 pin wire harness plugged into the control board. Turn off power to the unit. Unplug the harness from the board, and check continuity between pins 6 and 11 (should be the only two yellow wires). That will tell you if the limits are closed, which they should be.

Comment: I will try the continuity check on the control board next.  One thing I found is that then I disconnected a limit switch - it resembles a small black business card with two terminals, OEM part  SWT01257  - I pulled off both terminals - and made a call for heat.  The inducer/drafter fired up. However the igniter never fired up, I assume because the limit switch was now no longer in line.  I put the leads into each wire I had pulled from the switch, and I got 25 volts.  I kept one lead in the wire from the board and touched the other lead on each of the pressure switches - I got 25v on each one.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the reset procedure.  I did however turn the thermostat to off, turn down the thermostat to the lowest setting, and I cycled the power twice within thirty seconds.  I pulled the12 pin harness and inserted the meter leads into the two receptacles that had yellow wires - there is continuity when I do that.  I tested continuity at the limit switch (SWT01257) and there is continuity across those terminals as well.

Comment: If you removed the wires from the limit switch, you created an break (open) in the limit circuit. In this situation the furnace should not operate, though the blower or inducer might come on to clear the excess heat that the furnace thinks exists. Without actually being there, it's difficult to make the determination. I'd be leaning towards the possibility that the control board is bad, as it seems to be acting strange.

Comment: If you tested closed between the yellow wires (limit circuit), that means all the limits are closed as they should be.  So something else is causing the draft motor not to start.  I can't think of anything other than the control module, that could be responsible.  But again, without being there, I'm not comfortable telling the board is bad.

Comment: If one of the limiter switches is not good, could that be the problem? Am I correct in thinking that if I make a call for heat and put the probes on each terminal of the limiter, then I should be getting a constant 24V across the limiter terminals? I realize I would need to pull back the wires a bit from the limiter terminals to expose enough so the probes could touch the limiter terminals.

Comment: Limit switches are just switches. If you put one probe on each limit terminal, you should measure 0 volts (unless the switch is open).  An open limit indicates a problem, so if all the limits are closed, the system assumes all is well. When you checked continuity between the yellow wires, it showed that all the limits are closed.

Comment: After a bit more research, I found that during a 1st stage heat call, the low speed of the inducer is energized. So there should be line voltage between the white and red wires at the inducer.

Comment: I tried the probes into the white and red female ports after disconnecting the plug. Approx every 45 seconds or so the control panel will click - I assume this is call for heat as I have the thermostat turned up high and the house is cold.  Each time I hear the click, the voltmeter registers nothing.  If it's sounding like the board, I can track one down via a HVAC supplier.

Comment: I probed the white and red ports after disconnecting the plug. Approx every 45 seconds the control panel will click - I assume a call for heat as I have the thermostat turned up high.  Each time I hear the click, the voltmeter registers nothing.  If it's sounding like the board, I can track one down via a HVAC supplier. I have a question regarding pressure switches if I can go off on a tangent.  When testing the switches I  may have switched the wires when I remounted.  I have a P01 HI .50"  and a P02 LOW .17". Which one comes on 1st? And should the P01 HI have a wire going into the gas valve?

Comment: Check the schematic. The one I'm looking at shows an orange and two yellow wires on PS1, and an orange and two brown on PS2. Looks like one of the brown wires from PS2 goes to the gas valve. Again, I'm not familiar with your unit, I'm going off manuals I found online.

Comment: Thank you ... it appears the board is bad, as I am not getting power to the inducer motor, yet I have confirmed the inducer works.  My limit switches are closed and the pressure switches seem to be clicking on/off when I create pressure by sucking on them. So as far as the board it's a White Rodgers 50A51-507.  These seem hard to come by, is there a replacement? And if yes, is it a matter of plugging the wires in an identical fashion, and setting switches in an identical fashion. I will tape/identify the old wires, and photo everything first.

Comment: You might have to contact a local HVAC company (possibly the one that installed the unit), to find a replacement.  As for hooking it up. I would imagine a replacement would be fairly similar, at least as far as accepting the same wire harness configurations.  The DIP switches might be slightly different, so you'll want to consult the documentation for both boards.

Comment: using meter at the board, if I probe a hot 120V pin/connector  with for example the white (N) of the igniter, I get ~120V.  Same goes if I probe a hot 120V with the white (N) low speed inducer fan.  But no volts if probe lo speed inducer and white(N) of the inducer. So no hot 120V to the low speed inducer connection (plug pin).  If $450 board is bad, can anyone  let me know if reasonable to discon power, remove board, and check solder trace to the dead pin? If that pin worked I'd have a working low speed inducer and rest would fire.

Comment: If it's just a bad neutral in the harness, you could use a neutral from somewhere else on the board.  Some boards have extra neutral terminals, that are used for accessories.  If there's an open one, you could use that instead.

Comment: The board might have a neutral terminal for a humidifier (HUM) or air cleaner (EAC), for example.  If one of those is unused, you could use that to supply a neutral to the inducer. It's not common, but it should get you up and running.

Comment: I think it's the hot wire male pin on the board that's no good (female wire colored red on the inducer's and igniter's plug into the board). I do have a HUM with a 120VAC black wire going into it - and my unit does not have a humidifier as far as I know (no water plumbed into furnace). Am I correct in thinking I could use that HUM hot pin on the board, run a wire out from there, and splice into the inducer's low speed red wire and a convenient spot?

Comment: and do I need to change dip switches? At present dis 1-4 are off,5-6 are on, 7 is off, 8 is on.

Comment: I thought you said the **neutral** going to the inducer was bad?  If that's the case, you can use a **neutral** from elsewhere.  If the hot is bad, you **cannot** borrow that from somewhere else.  When the inducer is supposed to be on, if you measure 120 volts between the red wire at the inducer and ground, but not between the red and white wire at the inducer. Then the neutral from the board to the inducer is bad.

Comment: Maybe I'm not explaining things well enough. It might be time to get somebody who knows what they're doing, to come take a look.

Comment: I think the inducers neutral is OK here's why.  When I make a call for heat and nothing happens, if I pull a connection off of any of the limit switches be it high pressure limit switch or the flame switches, both the blower and the inducer come on.  Thus if the inducer is coming on its neutral must be OK. In listening to the board click when it makes a call for heat, my theory is the board is sending voltage to the igniter.  If the igniter is working OK then the inducer will immediately start.  When I put my meter on the igniter I get continuity but the voltage is very brief and then nothing.

Comment: When you intentionally open the limit circuit, you're signalling a fault to the system. That's why the blower and inducer both come on.  In this state, pull the wire harness off the inducer, and measure voltage between the white wire and the black wire, and the white wire and the red wire. Also measure from ground to the black wire, and ground to the red wire.  I'm guessing that during a fault, the high speed on the inducer is energized.  (*CONTINUED*)

Comment: (*CONTINUED*) If that's the case, then one of the following is likely true: 1.) The board is not energizing the low speed inducer terminal. 2.) The low speed wire to the inducer is damaged (broken). 3.) The low speed on the inducer is dead.

Comment: Here's the results after calling for heat and then opening a limit switch to cause a fault. Probes in the harness which is connected to board.  White-Black 0, White-Red 115, Ground-Black 0, Ground-Red 116.  If I then reconnect the plug thereby allowing energy to the inducer, it spins up. Thus it seems inducer low speed is OK.  Something is not allowing the inducer to go, I'm wondering if perhaps before the inducer can get energized by the board the board first checks with the igniter. If igniter answers back that it's healthy, inducer then starts up, igniter beings its glow 17 seconds later.

Comment: The inducer should start before the igniter. The igniter should only heat up, if the pressure switch closes. When the inducer is running during a fault, do one or both of the pressure switches close?

Comment: I can't find any documentation that says which speed the inducer should be run at, during normal operation. However, you said during normal operation, white to red and white to black gives 0 volts.  So in either case, the board is not energizing the inducer during normal operation

Comment: I made some progress but I'm not sure what to do next.  I placed a wire between the two leads on the low pressure 17"WC switch, and this caused the inducer to start immediately, followed by a glowing igniter and then ignition of the gas.  The furnace then ran for about 10 minutes, maybe 15 I didn't time it.  Then the flame extinguished and the blower kept going.  The flame sensor is brand new, and my guess is the old one was good as well.  So what's occurring here?  I can more or less jump start the furnace, but regardless of whether I leave the jumper wire, it will only go about 15 min.

Comment: So the furnace shuts down before the thermostat is satisfied?  If that's the case, check the board for an error code, and check the high limit switch.  It could be that the furnace is overheating.  Check the exhaust line for obstruction. If the furnace has a combustion air intake, check that for obstruction as well.  You should **not** run the furnace without the pressure switch, as combustion byproducts could be building up in your home.

Comment: I will check for error codes and obstruction.  How do I check the high limit switch?  Also am I correct in thinking at a minimum I need to replace the low pressure switch? The one that's in my furnace does not seem to be in production any longer.

Comment: I watched the furnace for 10-12 min, at which point it was shutting down.  At the stage where it shuts down, I think it's trying to go into a higher speed and draw more gas.  At that stage, I jumped the low pressure switch, again, and the igniter relit and the gas burned. However, and yes I am careful, the burners then got into what I will describe as an over-flame.  It was no longer a clean blue flame but more of a messy flame spilling out.  This tripped the heat sensor switch on the end of the manifold, I watched it trip.  Has happened twice now. Is it a case of no high speed on drafter?

Comment: To test the high limit switch, check continuity across the terminals. It will be open if the switch is tripped.  Something is wrong with the inducer/board/pressure switch, which is causing all the problems.

Comment: You shouldn't bypass the saftey features on the furnace, as it could lead to damage, injury, and/or death.

Comment: I purchased a new low/high pressure switch. Same problem exists.  I can only start the furnace if I jump the two terminals on the low pressure switch and wait there for 17 seconds for the igniter to ignite the gas. Gas then burns for 9 min 45 seconds, and low pressure switch gets pinged again with 24 volts.  But furnace shuts down. Maybe the board?  Flame sensor new, igniter works well, new pressure switch made no diff, flue is clear - I have vacuum pressure evidenced by furnace will shut down immediately if I pull off the vacuum hose while it's running. Board not testing open/close on switch?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps whomever has a similar prob.  Unplug the harness that connects the Fasco inducer and put the meter probes into the white and black (high speed is black) female ports.  Do a call for heat and if no power then it's most likely the board failing to energize the HIGH speed of the Fasco.  But check your three temp switches first for continuity (normally closed) and check both pressure switches for no continuity (normally open).  If your switches  are as they should be then it's probably the board.  I purchased an aftermarket board 21v51u-843 for half of the cost of the White Rodgers board.  New board has thermo terminals integrated, old one does not. Label with tape all of your wires first with initials such as EAC, HUM, XFMR, etc. then remove all wires.  Match the dip switch settings on new board, follow manual - note dip switches are in a new location and in a reverse order! The manual will show an example of the switches. Then plug into new board according to labels and attach thermostat wires. New board is a diff size thus I mounted it with wire thru the board's holes and made sure it was secure.  Furnace works fine now.  As always turn off all power before doing any work on the board and take several photos of the old board's wiring and dip switches to use as a reference.